# Python regular expression for getting html code excluding commented code in page source

Tags: python, regex

i wanted to get the page source excluding the commented code as string by using regular expressions. for ex :

```
<html>
<head>
<p>some code</p>
<!--
 <link href='www.xxx.com'>
 -->
<head>
<body>
<p>some more code</p>
</body></html>
```

is it possible to get the code which is not commented by using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the desired output by removing those commented lines.

```
re.sub(r'(?s)<!--.*?-->', '', html)
```

*Example:*

```
>>> html = '''<html>
<head>
<p>some code</p>
<!--
 <link href='www.xxx.com'>
 -->
<head>
<body>
<p>some more code</p>
</body></html>'''
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?s)\s*<!--.*?-->', '', html))
<html>
<head>
<p>some code</p>
<head>
<body>
<p>some more code</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: makes dot in your regex to match line breaks.

Comment: And how did you ping me without writing my username in your comment like this `@Shafizade` ?

Comment: Because SO assumes that I replied to your comment.

Comment: Now SO shows you a notification? (if yes, the reason is being just you and me in this conversion?)